# PHP - While/foreach in a class: stuck, can’t figure out what to do

Tags: php, arrays, class, foreach, while-loop

I’m learning (well, attempting to) OOP and I have one simple and possibly very silly question. 
I have to retrieve some data from a very “deep” array. If I were to use a procedural approach, I would declare a variable like this, just for the sake of readability:

```
    foreach ( $my_array as $single ) {

        $readable = $single['level_1']['level_2']['level_3']['something'];

    }
```

And while inside that foreach, I could use `$readable` as I like.
Right now I’m attempting to build a class and I need to handle the same array. I would be tempted to do something like this in order to make things more clear:

```
class MyClass {

protected $my_array = null;

protected function myCustomIncrement() {

    return $readable++;

}

public function myCustomOutput() {

    foreach ( $this->my_array as $single ) {

        $readable = $single['level_1']['level_2']['level_3']['something'];

        return $this->myCustomIncrement();

    }


}

}

$test = new MyClass;
echo $test>myCustomOutput();
```

But while inside `myCustomIncrement()` both `$readable` or `$this->$readable` result undefined. I’m probably attempting to do something really silly, which is why I’d like to ask for help: how can I make use of a foreach or while keeping a clean/readable/maintainable code? Or maybe I should use a different approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `$readable` value to `myCustomIncrement()` method and have it incremented there. So your `myCustomIncrement()` and `myCustomOutput()` methods would be like this:

```
protected function myCustomIncrement($readable) {
    return ++$readable;
}

public function myCustomOutput() {
    foreach( $this->my_array as $single ) {
        $readable = $single['level_1']['level_2']['level_3']['something'];
        return $this->myCustomIncrement($readable);
    }
}
```

Make the increment operation pre-increment like `return ++$readable;`, not post-increment, so that the method could return the updated value.

Comment: Just a sidenote, take care of the `return` statement inside `foreach` loop. In the current scenario, once the `return` statement is hit, the control goes back to the calling function statement. So basically, your `foreach` loop will get executed **only once**.

Comment: Thanks! I thought of placing $readable as a parameter, but I did that only for myCustomIncrement(). And thank you very much also for your other tips!